# Can't build Boost 1.59 error: feature "deduced-address-model" : "32" "64" : "propagated" "optional" "composite" "hidden"

Tags: c++, boost

I unsuccessfully trying to build boost under osx

What I tried

1. `git checkout boost-1.59.0`
2. `./bootstrap.sh`

> `Building Boost.Build engine with toolset darwin... tools/build/src/engine/bin.macosxx86_64/b2
>   Detecting Python version... 2.7
>   Detecting Python root... /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
>   Unicode/ICU support for Boost.Regex?... not found.
>   Generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam...`
>
> `Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:`
>
> `./b2`
>
> `To adjust configuration, edit 'project-config.jam'.`
>   `Further information:`
>
> `- Command line help:`
>   `./b2 --help`
>
> `- Getting started guide:`
>   `http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html`
>
> `- Boost.Build documentation:`
>   `http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/index.html`

3. `./b2`

> `/Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost/tools/build/src/build/feature.jam:139: in feature.feature from module feature
>   error: unknown attributes: hidden
>   error: in feature declaration:
>   error: feature "deduced-address-model" : "32" "64" : "propagated" "optional" "composite" "hidden"
>   /Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost/boostcpp.jam:611: in load from module boostcpp
>   /Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:289: in modules.import from module modules
>   /Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:1024: in import from module Jamfile</Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost>
>   Jamroot:124: in modules.load from module Jamfile</Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost>
>   /Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:311: in load-jamfile from module project
>   /Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:64: in load from module project
>   /Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:145: in project.find from module project
>   /Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:535: in load from module build-system
>   /Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:289: in import from module modules
>   /Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build from module
>   /Volumes/Data/Developers/Library/boost/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module`

So can someone explain what this error means? How to fix it?

*** Solution ***
I forgot to update submodules, my fault

Comment: No that is really strange! What commands are you passing to build? (or is that literally the default?)

Answer (score 0):

No that is really strange! 
What commands are you passing to build? (or is that literally the default?)

I recommend trying out one of my build scripts here:
https://github.com/danoli3/ofxOSXBoost

If that doesn't work either it may be a system conflict. 
Do you have Homebrew or Macports installed? See if they have a Boost version installed.

Comment: Yes, default, `./bootstrap.sh && ./b2`

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Otherwise it's just a link to your Github repo and is effectively spam.

Comment: @Danoli3 I'm new in boost world, could you please explain why you added separate script if building should work out of box in boost? (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @CAMOBAP some commands are needed for example, you need to set the minimum target now with Xcode 7 or receive build warning. Other explicit things, such as passing -fPIC, the C++ standard (c11), weather it is libc++ or libstdc++